# Angular2 App not correct initialize on browser refresh

Tags: angular

While developing first Angular2 app I stumble on a problem when app is refreshed in browser.

To use app, user need to be authentificate.
I have authenticationService which handle this, and when user is login, data is fetched and store in this authenticationService.

App have 2 guards, CanActivate and Resolve guard.

Resolve guard, return true if user data exist in authenticationService.
If not or error happened, app is navigate to login page.

I have dataComponent, which on init call method from dataService using userId.
userId is read from authenticationService, from userData.

Following scenario crash app.
User is logged and everything works fine.

When browser is refreshed, dataComponent is initialize before authenticationService fetch user data.
Because of that, wrong userId is send to dataService and app crash.

This happens even with resolve guard activated. 
DataComponent is initialized before resolve guard get user data. And OnInit DataComponent call dataService method with wrong userId. And again, app crash.

**Questions:**

Resolve guard should be used to not load route before data is there, right?
Then why component is initialized before Resolve guard respond?

Do you have some proposal how to fix this problem?

**Solution:**
Solution come from the answered question. Here how code looks.

Resolver guard:

```
 resolve(): Observable<UserData> {
    return this.authenticationService.getUserData();
```

Routing:

```
{ path: 'admin/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, resolve: {user: ResolverGuard} },
```

Dashboard:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data:{user:UserData}) => {
        if (data.user) {
            this.dashboardService.getDashboard(data.user.id)
                .subscribe(dashboard => { this.dashboard = dashboard }, err => console.log(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code for your service and guards?

Comment: Code is added . Looking forward for responses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolver is not a guard but a way to load the data for component and you need to access this resolved data in the component like:

```
  // routing
  {
    path: 'myroute',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {user: MyResolver}
  }

 // component constructor
 constructor(...
          private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  // ngOnInit
 this.activatedRoute.data
  .subscribe((data: {user}) => {
    // do stuff
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Refreshing issue is solved. Just for other people I will change code in question so they have example